# VSCode Python Windows: debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm trying to setup a new laptop, some how got things work on my old one but now I can't seem to debug and some packages that used to work no long work.  I followed other suggestions and have my virtual env and pip installed the packages I neded.  But the only way I can debug is by selecting the ... at the top (next to View), Run and Start Debuggingfrom .  F5 doesnt work and the Icon on the left changed from a sidewise trangle to a square (Remote explorer) what is the missing piece?

Can't debug, it just runs and there are unexpected results from things like argparse.

Comment: Have you installed the Python Extension?

Comment: Yes, I followed the MS instructions; first installed python (3.12.1) w/ extensions.  also created the virt environment and I can see my pip install are going into the environment

Answer (score 0):

When you use a new environment, you need to install all the packages required for your code.

If there is no debugging panel on the left side of vscode, try the following steps:

1. Right click on the right side
2. Check if **Run and Debugging** is checked

   [image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by the right side, I don't see the triangle w/ the bug in the left but the debug (triangle w/ a bug on it) in the upper far right (2nd line down) if I select that it just runs and ignores my breakpoints.  Also (2nd problem) is that there are packages in my .venv\lib\site-packages but think they are being ignored.  For example if I try to pip install PyYAML, it says the folder is not writable and is satisfyed by the global/user instance.  Is there a pip command that will tell me the environment/directory used? (admin on this windows laptop)

Comment: Show off your interface. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, first things first - starting a new python project on windows w/ VSCode.  Why doesn't it support debugging.  Both F5 and the icon just runs through the code and ignores my breakpoints.

Comment: Edit your question, describe your movements step by step, give your minimum code.    Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)